# Question About ECC Primitives (GnuPG)

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, pgp

In version 2.1, GnuPG featured primitives that use elliptic curves. For encryption, one option was ECDH, which confused me. I thought ECDH was for key agreement, not public key encryption. How does GnuPG utilize a key agreement scheme for enciphering files/messages?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6637#section-8

> Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) in OpenPGP

> ...

> 8. EC DH Algorithm (ECDH)

> The method is a combination of an ECC Diffie-Hellman method to
> establish a shared secret, a key derivation method to process the
> shared secret into a derived key, and a key wrapping method that uses
> the derived key to protect a session key used to encrypt a message.

> The One-Pass Diffie-Hellman method C(1, 1, ECC CDH) [NIST-SP800-56A]
> MUST be implemented with the following restrictions: the ECC CDH
> primitive employed by this method is modified to always assume the
> cofactor as 1, the KDF specified in Section 7 is used, and the KDF
> parameters specified below are used.

> ...

> The key wrapping method is described in [RFC3394].  KDF produces a
> symmetric key that is used as a key-encryption key (KEK) as specified
> in [RFC3394].  Refer to Section 13 for the details regarding the
> choice of the KEK algorithm, which SHOULD be one of three AES
> algorithms.  Key wrapping and unwrapping is performed with the
> default initial value of [RFC3394].

> ...